# book recommendation for problem-solving

Tags: problem-solving, book-recommendation

I think russians are great mathematicians:pelerman, kolmogorov stanislav smirnov and etc.I am interested in:what kind of mathematical education they have, so that they were able to achieve that much?can you suggest some problem solving books or any suggestions that would help me to rise my math skill and problem solving ability?

Comment: Check out artofproblemsolving.com. Also, I think The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Zeitz is a great book.

Comment: i know both of these.i practiced for about 2 years and didn't get significant result, there is why i think that i miss something, maybe another book or something else.

Comment: Which books have you read? What kind of practice did you do / how would you describe your approach to training?

Comment: at first i started doing national olympiad problems without any problem solving methods, i noticed that i lost 1 year,than i read following books:problem solving strategies by engel,books which you mentioned above, problem-solving methods in combinatorics by Pablo Soberion,IMO compendium(about 20 pages), putnam and beyond, and number thery by Sato(i read that at the beginning).i practiced 4-5 hours a day.for two years.i would say now i am on IMO 1st problem level, but i want to be on 3rd problem level and don't know what to do.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen can help you out. He participated in IMO and won bronze medal in 1984, gold medal in 1985.

Comment: IMO 1st problem level is not a bad place to be; my two cents is just to keep it up and keep improving. It's only been two years of training so far. If it's possible to attend a summer math program or a math circle where you interact with other great students that can help a lot. You could try actually taking some of the AoPS courses. Also keep in mind that mastering contest math is not the only valid goal in the world; plenty of awesome mathematicians and scientists and engineers haven't trained for olympiad math problems and aren't especially good at them.

Comment: so what do you suggest? any contact people? i am currently on my second year of university, and i am told that olympiad mathematics is not the subject to waste my time.Any suggestions to rise my math level upto the level of great mathematician?

Comment: Personally, I would not focus on contest math at this point. Your problem solving is already excellent. I would just learn as much higher math or whatever subject excites you as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself have been doing lots of research and reading numerous reviews and descriptions on which books are best to improve one's problem-solving skills, so I feel that I should share the outcome of the hours I spent searching the web with others (note: These are not my reviews, I still have NOT purchased any of these books or read them)

- **The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Paul Zaitz:** high school level
- **The Art of Problem Solving, Volume 1:The Basics (7th edition on Amazon):** middle school competitions(also prepares for high school)-high school students. GOOD OPTION TO CONSIDER
- **Solving Mathematical Problems by Tao:** aimed to 14-15yrs audience. A comment said it's not enough for a training curriculum for high-level math competitions. Another comment said its a very very bad option & not to be considered. Many highly recommended it.
- **A Mathematical Mosaic: Patterns & Problem Solving:** "seventh- and eighth- grade students can handle yet high school students will find challenging." It seems not like a textbook or a solid curriculum, not the best as a reference.
- **Problem-Solving through Problems:** I feel it's for Putnam exams and upper high school level, it seems a great, organized book. Highly recommended by many.
- **Mathematical Olympiad Challenges, Second Edition:** seems for up-to-calculus students, very great, organized, and great results of acquiring methods and techniques.
- **Mathematical Discovery:** high-school, college students one review said "read over several years"
- **Problem-Solving Strategies In Mathematics: From Common Approaches To Exemplary Strategies:** seems like a very good stepping stone, I would advise buying it, solving it, and then solving another harder book. I guess that would be a nearly perfect option to consider.
- **Introduction to Algebra--Introduction to Geometry:** good for middle school level(even maybe not that progressive) Not only word problems, a drawback: just algebra/geometry
- **How To Solve It:** not sure about the age it's aimed to, but I guess it is great for high-school and college students.It seems general without enough practice but is definitely a classic. OPTION TO PROBABLY CONSIDER WITH A PRACTICE BOOK